# UITableView: contentOffset is changing automatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios11

I have a UITableView with each cell containing a UICollectionView. Each cell can be expanded/collapsed. While doing so the tableView's contentOffset changes, which when goes negative causes a gap in the beginning of the tableView, making the first cell itself to start from half of the tableView.

It seems to work properly for iOS 9, iOS 10 and iOS11.1.2. Only in case of iOS11.2.1, the issue is there.

Can anyone help with the issue?

Comment: invalidate the layout of tableview before reloading.

Comment: have you tried to do view.layoutIfNeeded() when you change things?

Comment: It seems to work properly for iOS 9, iOS 10 and iOS11.1.2. Only in case of iOS11.2.1, the issue is there.
I tried to solve it  with the patch :
if self.tableView.contentOffset.y < 0.0 {
                            self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), animated: true)
                            }

Is this an iOS issue ?

Comment: `self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.
Your view controller has property called

```
Adjusts Scroll View Insets
```

Make it `False`